# Hide specific variable from the hover text of plotly chart with two traces

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I have the dataframe below and create a `plotly` plot object with inner circles. My issue is that I want to skip the `value` from both the gray and the green dots.

```
i <- 1

f<-bt %>% filter(issue==unique(bt$issue)[1]) %>%
ggplot(aes(x=year2))+
  
  geom_point(aes(y=value,size=value),color="gray")+
  geom_point(aes(y=value,size=percent),color="darkolivegreen")+
  scale_x_continuous(n.breaks=14)+
  theme(legend.position = 'none',
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank())+
  labs(x="")

p2<-ggplotly(f)

p2$x$data[[1]]$text <- str_replace_all(p2$x$data[[1]]$text, 
                                       "year2", "Year") %>% 
  str_replace_all(., fixed("percent"),
                  "Percentage of all signed PTAs covering NTIs")

p2$x$data[[2]]$text <- str_replace_all(p2$x$data[[2]]$text, 
                                       "year2", "Year") %>% 
  str_replace_all(., fixed("percent"),
                  "Percentage of all signed PTAs covering NTIs")

p2
```

My data:

```
bt<-structure(list(year2 = c(1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 
    1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 
    1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 
    1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 
    1950, 1950, 1950, 1950, 1955, 1955, 1955, 1955, 1955, 1955, 1955, 
    1955, 1955, 1955, 1955, 1955, 1955, 1955, 1955, 1955, 1955, 1955, 
    1955, 1955, 1955, 1955, 1955, 1955, 1955, 1955, 1955), issue = c("air", 
    "anti_corruption", "anti_drug", "anti_terror", "biodiversity", 
    "chemical", "child", "contaminant", "cpr", "csr", "democracy", 
    "development", "eductation", "environmental_goods_services", 
    "ep", "esr", "fish_stock", "food_security", "forest", "gender", 
    "good_governance", "health", "human_trafficking", "labor_at", 
    "labor_at_child", "labor_at_equal_opportunity", "labor_at_forced", 
    "labor_at_health_and_safety", "labor_at_minimum_wage", "labor_at_unionize", 
    "labor_at_working_time", "labor_to", "migrantworker", "mineral", 
    "minority", "national_security", "region", "religion", "renewable_energy", 
    "rule_of_law", "social", "waste", "water", "air", "air", "anti_corruption", 
    "anti_corruption", "anti_drug", "anti_drug", "anti_terror", "anti_terror", 
    "biodiversity", "biodiversity", "chemical", "chemical", "child", 
    "child", "contaminant", "contaminant", "cpr", "cpr", "csr", "csr", 
    "democracy", "democracy", "development", "development", "eductation", 
    "eductation", "environmental_goods_services"), value = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, NA, NA, 8, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, NA, 
    NA, NA, 16, NA, NA, NA, NA, 8, NA, NA, NA, NA, 12, 1, NA, NA, 
    12, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 24, 2, NA, NA, 12, 1, 
    36, 3, NA, NA, NA), percent = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 0.125, NA, NA, 0.125, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.125, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.125, NA, NA, NA, 0.0625, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.125, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.0833333333333333, 2, 
    NA, NA, 0.0833333333333333, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    0.0416666666666667, 1, NA, NA, 0.0833333333333333, 2, 0.0277777777777778, 
    0.666666666666667, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -70L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I removed the filter so that points plotted. If you want the same tooltip in all points, you can add the `text` to `ggplot(aes())`. If you still wanted `percent` in the `darkolivegreen` points, you will need to add the `text` to the layers.

Just years, with text in `ggplot()`:

```
f <- bt %>% # filter(issue == unique(bt$issue)[1]) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year2, text = paste0("Year: ", year2))) +
  geom_point(aes(y = value, size = value), color = "gray") +
  geom_point(aes(y = value, size = percent), color = "darkolivegreen") +
  scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 14) +
  theme(legend.position  =  'none',
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = "")

ggplotly(f, tooltip = "text")
```

If you want the values from `percent` on the appropriate points, use this option. By the way, I've formatted the `percent` data as percentages. I provided two different ways of doing this. One of the methods is commented out. The one that is not commented out uses the `scale` package. Both work; it's up to you, of course.

```
f <- bt %>% # filter(issue == unique(bt$issue)[1]) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = year2)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = value, size = value, text = paste0("Year: ", year2)),
             color = "gray") +
  geom_point(aes(y = value, size = percent,
                 # text = paste0("Year: ", year2, "\nPercent: ", round(percent, 3) * 100, "%")), 
                 text = paste0("Year: ", year2, "\nPercent: ", scales::percent(percent))), 
             color = "darkolivegreen") +
  scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 14) +
  theme(legend.position  =  'none',
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = "")

ggplotly(f, tooltip = "text")
```

[image] [image]

Comment: maybe u could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71394798/set-the-number-of-decimals-in-values-dipslayed-in-gpplotly