# Set the number of decimals in values dipslayed in gpplotly()

Tags: r, ggplotly

I have the dataframe below:

```
dt2<-structure(list(year2 = c(1950, 1955, 1960, 1965, 1970, 1975, 
1980, 1985, 1990, 1995, 2000, 2005, 2010, 2015), pta_count = c(2, 
4, 10, 14, 24, 18, 13, 19, 84, 100, 105, 96, 47, 15), scope_ntis_mean = c(3.5, 
9.5, 5, 9.57142857142857, 4.54166666666667, 11.7222222222222, 
6.23076923076923, 7.05263157894737, 17.1071428571429, 15.16, 
15.2761904761905, 17.6354166666667, 22.9574468085106, 26.8666666666667
), scope_ntis_sd = c(0.707106781186548, 11.7046999107196, 6.25388767976457, 
8.72409824049971, 4.56812364359683, 9.2278705436976, 5.11784209333462, 
10.7779284971676, 13.2864799994027, 12.9643801053175, 12.1295056958191, 
12.7964796077233, 12.4375963125981, 14.5791762782532), scope_ntis_se = c(0.822426813475736, 
9.62625905026287, 3.25294959458435, 3.83516264302846, 1.53376734188638, 
3.57760589505535, 2.33476117415722, 4.06710846230115, 2.38450123589789, 
2.13245076374089, 1.94704374916827, 2.14823678655809, 2.98410970181292, 
6.19176713030084), scope_ntis_cil = c(2.67757318652426, -0.12625905026287, 
1.74705040541565, 5.73626592840011, 3.00789932478029, 8.14461632716687, 
3.89600805661201, 2.98552311664622, 14.722641621245, 13.0275492362591, 
13.3291467270222, 15.4871798801086, 19.9733371066977, 20.6748995363658
), scope_ntis_ciu = c(4.32242681347574, 19.1262590502629, 8.25294959458435, 
13.406591214457, 6.07543400855305, 15.2998281172776, 8.56553040492645, 
11.1197400412485, 19.4916440930407, 17.2924507637409, 17.2232342253587, 
19.7836534532248, 25.9415565103236, 33.0584337969675)), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and I create plot with `ggplotly()` in which I want every `y` number when you hover over plot to have only 2 decimals. I use `format(round(x, 2), nsmall = 2)` but I get :

```
Discrete value supplied to continuous scale


p<-ggplotly(ggplot(dt2, aes(x=year2)) + 
              
              geom_col(aes(y=pta_count/(max(dt2$pta_count)/max(dt2$scope_ntis_ciu))
                           
              ),
              fill="darkolivegreen",alpha=0.3,width=3)+
              geom_point(aes(y=scope_ntis_mean
              ))+
              geom_segment(aes(x=year2,y=scope_ntis_cil,xend=year2,yend=scope_ntis_ciu
              ),
              arrow=arrow(length=unit(0.1,"cm"),
                          ends='both'),
              lineend="square",size=0.3) +
              scale_x_continuous(n.breaks=14)+
              # Custom the Y scales:
              scale_y_continuous(
                
                # Features of the first axis
                name = "NTI Scope\n(scope measures the sum of all NTIs mentioned in a PTA,\ndot indicated mean scope per 5-year interval,\n arrows signal confidence intervals)",
                
                # Add a second axis and specify its features
                sec.axis = sec_axis( ~ . * max(dt2$pta_count)/max(dt2$scope_ntis_ciu), name="PTA Count\n(green columns indicate number of PTAs\n signed in given 5-year intervall)")
              )+
              labs(x='')+
              theme_bw()+theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 8),
                               axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 20, b = 0, l = 0)),
                               text=element_text( family="Montserrat") ))%>% 
  add_trace(inherit = F, x = ~year2,
            y = ~(pta_count/(max(pta_count)/ max(scope_ntis_ciu))
            ) * (max(dt2$pta_count)/max(dt2$scope_ntis_ciu)),
            data = dt2, 
            yaxis = "y2", 
            hoverinfo="skip",
            alpha = 0,                        # make it invisible
            type = "bar") %>% 
  layout(margin = list(l = 85, r = 85),
         yaxis2 = list(
           ticklen = 3.7,                     # to match other axes
           tickcolor = "rgba(51, 51, 51, 1)", # to match other axes
           tickfont = list(size = 11.7,       # to match other axes
                           color = "rgba(77, 77, 77, 1)"), # to match the others
           titlefont = list(size = 11.7),     # to match other axes
           side = "right",    
           overlaying = "y",
           showgrid = F,      # to match ggplot version
           dtick = 25,        # between ticks
           title = "PTA Count\n(green columns indicate number of PTAs\n signed in given 5-year interval)"))

p
```

Comment: You can round columns in your `dt2` and save it to another variable and use it to plot. Maybe something like `dt3 <- dt2 %>% mutate(across(c(scope_ntis_cil, scope_ntis_ciu, scope_ntis_mean), ~round(.x, digit = 2)))`

Comment: You can manually change the `hovertemplate` as such: `p$x$data[[2]]$hovertemplate <- "x=%{x}<br>y=%{y}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to round your data *before* graphing, round the data in the data frame before making the `ggplot` object, as @benson23 advised.

Like @Bas advised, you can modify the `hovertemplate`. You will need to do this for each trace (one for each `geom`). It doesn't have to be *exactly* as he has written this, you could write `"Year: %{x}<br>Count of Issues: %{y}"` for `p$x$data[[2]]`, which is the `geom_point` layer (or trace when it is `plotly`).

[image]

I benefit from knowing that you wanted custom labels, either way. If you're going to round the labels, especially custom labels, round them when you create the labels.

I've added `text` to each `geom_`. (I used `round`, but `format` would have worked there, as well.)

> I also added `tooltip = "text"` to the `ggplotly()` call (easy to forget that part!).

```
(p <- ggplotly(
  ggplot(dt2, aes(x = year2)) + 
    geom_col(aes(y = pta_count/(max(pta_count)/max(scope_ntis_ciu)), 
                 text = paste0("Year: ", year2,
                               "\nCount of Issues: ",      # rounded
                               round(pta_count/(max(pta_count)/max(scope_ntis_ciu)), 2)) 
                 ), 
             fill = "darkolivegreen", alpha = 0.3, width = 3) +
    geom_point(aes(y = scope_ntis_mean,
                   text = paste0("Year: ", year2,
                                 "\nCount of Issues: ",     # rounded
                                 round(scope_ntis_mean, 2))
                   )) +
    geom_segment(aes(x = year2, y = scope_ntis_cil, 
                     xend = year2, yend = scope_ntis_ciu,
                     text = paste0("Year: ", year2,
                                   "\nCount of Issues: ",   # rounded
                                   round(scope_ntis_cil, 2),
                                   "\nThe other issues?: ", # rounded
                                   round(scope_ntis_ciu, 2))
                     ), 
                 arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.1, "cm"), ends = 'both'), 
                 lineend = "square", size = 0.3) + 
    scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 14) +
    # Custom the Y scales:
    scale_y_continuous(
      # Features of the first axis
      name = "NTI Scope\n(scope measures the sum of all NTIs mentioned in a PTA, \ndot indicated mean scope per 5-year interval, \n arrows signal confidence intervals)", 
      # Add a second axis and specify its features
      sec.axis = sec_axis( 
        ~ . * max(dt2$pta_count)/max(dt2$scope_ntis_ciu), 
        name = "PTA Count\n(green columns indicate number of PTAs\n signed in given 5-year intervall)")) +
    labs(x = '') +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 8), 
          axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 20, b = 0, l = 0)), 
          text = element_text( family = "Montserrat")),
  tooltip = "text") %>%                        # <<<----- tooltip = "text"
   add_trace(inherit = F, x = ~year2, 
             y = ~(pta_count/(max(pta_count)/ max(scope_ntis_ciu))
             ) * (max(dt2$pta_count)/max(dt2$scope_ntis_ciu)), 
             data = dt2, 
             yaxis = "y2", 
             hoverinfo = "skip", 
             alpha = 0,                        # make it invisible
             type = "bar") %>% 
   layout(margin = list(l = 85, r = 85), 
          yaxis2 = list(
            ticklen = 3.7,                     # to match other axes
            tickcolor = "rgba(51, 51, 51, 1)", # to match other axes
            tickfont = list(size = 11.7,       # to match other axes
                            color = "rgba(77, 77, 77, 1)"), # to match the others
            titlefont = list(size = 11.7),     # to match other axes
            side = "right",    
            overlaying = "y", 
            showgrid = F,      # to match ggplot version
            dtick = 25,        # between ticks
            title = "PTA Count\n(green columns indicate number of PTAs\n signed in given 5-year interval)")))
```

[image] [image] [image]